# Как сверстать загуголину?

Tags: html, css3, вёрстка

Взялся за верстку макета, и столкнулся с небольшой сложностью.

Есть картинка, под ней вот такая загуголина:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как такую-же сделать, только естественно на CSS?

Пока просто совместил картинку с загуголиной.
Желательно покажите примеры, буду благодарен.

Живой пример вёрстки: http://w-0rld.ru/

Comment: Сначала прочел как `заgoogleину` :)

Comment: Какая загогулина? Зачем css, если можно просто отрезать картинку с белым куском?

Comment: Для адаптации под все разрешения.

Comment: @HR-DEV а сейчас в чем проблема с адаптацией?

Comment: То что размер картинки не позволяет использовать ее под все разрешения. Допустим 4k, и что мне, файл размером от 5мб загружать?

Comment: Если я использую слишком маленькое разрешение допустим, то отрезанная картинка не отображается полностью.